# Does SIV mode work for asymmetric encryption?

Tags: hash, public-key, deterministic-encryption, siv, ecies

In ECIES and similar asymmetric schemes, is it possible to use a hash of the plaintext as the IV?

Comment: That's certainly _possible_, but doing so is not secure. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer why is this?

Comment: Doing so reveals the hash of the plaintext. ​ (That lets someone test guesses at the plaintext.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the hash of the message as IV would not be secure, since, like Ricky Demer mentioned in comments, it would make the hash public and allow guessing. However, that is not what SIV mode does – it uses a *MAC* as IV.

Doing that with ECIES would be possible, but probably not a good idea:

- Normal ECIES has single-use symmetric keys, so it requires no IVs.
- For the same reason ECIES+SIV would not be deterministic, if that is the objective.

Unless SIV happens to be the best kind of encryption available for other reasons, there is no advantage over other forms of authenticated encryption, and probably downsides like speed (since it requires two passes over the data).

With other asymmetric systems it may be another matter. E.g. Curve25519 uses static Diffie–Hellman keys for both the receiver and sender, so using SIV would avoid total breakage on nonce reuse.